# Presentation of finite abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

If $G$ a non cyclic abelian group, then $$G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}\cdots\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}.$$ Can we give any presentation of this?

My attempt-
$$G=\langle g_1g_2\cdots g_k:g_1^{n_1}=g_2^{n_1}=\cdots g_k^{n_k}=1, g_ig_j=g_jg_i;i,j=1,2,\cdots k \rangle,$$ where $\gcd(n_i,n_j)\neq 1, i\neq j, i,j=1,2\cdots k$.

Comment: Your presentation is fine, although $n_i$ need not be pairwise coprime, e.g $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

Comment: If $n_1,...,n_k$ are pairwise coprime then $G$ would be cyclic.

Comment: @quasi thanks for mentioning this. Now i have edited this, please have a look on this. Actually i have to avoid the case of being cyclic.

Comment: There is no need to assume that $G$ is not cyclic. Also, you should not be writing $g_i,g_j \in {\mathbb Z}_{n_i}$ in the middle of a group presentation. The $g_i$ are just abstract symbols.

Comment: @DerekHolt Actually i need presentation of finite noncyclic abelian groups. Please have a look sir, now i have edited this.

Comment: Yes it's correct now, but if you want $G$ to be non-cyclic, then yopu should also say that $k > 1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt   thanku for mentioning $k>1$ as this is trivial but very crucial point.